# Limit of an arithmetic average series

Tags: arithmetic, average, faq

Sorry in advance as English is not my primary language.

I randomly thought of the following simple problem, and I coudn't solve it after one one hour trying. Maybe you guys can help.

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be positive real numbers. Let $a_n$ be the arithmetic average of the previous 2 numbers, i.e.:

$$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$$

If I draw this as points on a paper, I can obviously see that the limit of $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is a function of $a_1$ and $a_2$, but I can't solve it.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Did you solve the recurrence equation ? If you did, did you apply the conditions ? By the way, **welcome** to the site !

Comment: You can try with, for example $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 =100$ and plot it! It gives an interesting graphical solution ...

Comment: Take a look at [Solving homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thank you! I didn't even know this was a "recurrence equation", I'm not a mathematician, just an Engineer.

Comment: @MattiP., You are right, that was helpful. I fount out that the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $\frac{a_1+2a_2}{3}$. However, I still can't find the solution for a general $a_n$.

Comment: @robjohn, Thanks. The solution is probably in the "Solving non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients" section, but that's too complicated for me, I don't know where to start. If the solution is trivial for my case, could you show me?

Comment: @AndersonLinhares: your's is a *homogeneous* linear recurrence with constant coefficients (which is why the link points to that section). The characteristic polynomial is $x^2-\frac12x-\frac12=(x-1)\left(x+\frac12\right)$, so the solution is $a_n=c_11^n+c_2\left(-\frac12\right)^n$ for some $c_1,c_2$ that depend on $a_1,a_2$. Note that as $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to c_1$.

Comment: @AndersonLinhares. Sorry for that ! I did not expect that you did not know. Next time, may be, you could precise what you know and if the question is related to homework/assignment or if you, as an engineer, are looking for some help. We are here ready to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the equation as

- $2a_n -a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} = 0$

you obtain a so called homogeneous linear difference equation.

This type of equation can be solved.

A possible method is to check what happens if you plug in a "guessed" solution of the form $a_n = c\cdot \lambda^n$ where $c$ is a real constant.

You will find that the solution can be written as 
$$a_n = c_1\cdot 1^n + c_2\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)^n = c_1 + c_2\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

The $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ come from solving the quadratic equation $2\lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0$ you will come across when you carry out the suggested approach $a_n = c\cdot \lambda^n$.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. This is not the solution though, right? Experimenting with the values, I'm certain that the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $\frac{a_1+2a_2}{3}$. I don't know what solution to "guess" to get an expression for $a_n$ though.

Comment: it is. it iis. you may use your two starting values to determine the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. i thought to leave this last step for you so you can play around with the general formula.